# Unfortunately, the app has stopped

Tags: android-emulator

I'm a beginner and am trying to do the Android tutorial about google maps on emulator, But every time I try to run my app, I have the following message

```
Unfortunately, <app name> has stopped
```

I have just tried to code the tutorial, nothing more than this, and it doesn't work!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: sorry but if you don't even point to the tutorial, how can you expect us to help you? welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

You could look in the code debugging window for error messages that include the line number where the failure occured and include that message here if you can't figure it out.